# CSRF session token

Tags: php, smarty

I'm trying to implement a simple CSRF protection on a form, but I can't get it right. If someone can point out what I'm doing wrong, I would appreciate it.

The error: Every time I submit the form, I get "Invalid Submission2" because the token changes (after the form is submitted), since is being generated on the same page?

Edit -- I forgot to mention, another file (config.php) already has session_start().

```
<?php
class Module_Post extends Base_Module {

    public function start()
    {
        requireLogin();

        if (isset($_GET['act'])) {
            switch($_GET['act']) {
                case 'text':
                    $this->text();
                    break;
                case 'image':
                    $this->image();
                    break;
                default:
                    $this->text();
                    break;
            }
        } else {
            $this->text();
        }
    }

    private function text()
    {

        // Generate random unique token to prevent cross-site request forgery (CSRF).
        if(empty($_SESSION['form_token'])) 
        {
            $form_token = md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE));
            $_SESSION['form_token'] = $form_token;
        }

        if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
        {
            // Clean the content from cross-site scripting (xss)
            $content = trim($_POST['content']);
            $content = Xss::clean($content);

            // Validate that the form token
            if(!isset($_POST['form_token'], $_SESSION['form_token'])) {
                $err = 'Invalid Submission';
            } elseif ($_POST['form_token'] != $_SESSION['form_token']) {
                $err = 'Invalid Submission2';
            } elseif (strlen($content) < 10) {
                $err = 'Your content contains too few characters.';
            }

            if(isset($err)) {
                unset( $_SESSION['form_token']);
                $this->setMessage($err, 'FAIL');
                header('Location: index.php?mod=post');
                exit;
            }


            // Insert database data here, then redirect

            $this->setMessage('Your post was published successfully.', 'GOOD');
            header('Location: index.php');
            exit;
        }

        $this->tpl->assign('form_token', $form_token);
        $this->tpl->display('new/text.tpl');
    }

}
?>
```

The HTML (text.tpl file)

```
<form method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' action='#'>
  <fieldset>
    <textarea rows="8" id="new_post" name="content" class="input-block-level"></textarea>
    <input type="hidden" name="form_token" value="{$form_token}" />
    <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-info pull-left">Create Post</button>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Have you started the session, so your session reading/writing works? Check that there the hidden element actually has a token in it too.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention, I already added the session_start(); somewhere else in another file (config.php). And the form shows the token. I think the problem is because the token is generated in the same page, once the form is submitted another token is generated and is checking for the old token.. hm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change this line

```
$this->tpl->assign('form_token', $form_token);
```

into:

```
$this->tpl->assign('form_token', $_SESSION['form_token']);
```

That's because you generate your token only with this condition:

```
if(empty($_SESSION['form_token'])) 
{
    $form_token = md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE));
    $_SESSION['form_token'] = $form_token;
}
```

and unset it using this condition:

```
if(isset($err)) {
    unset( $_SESSION['form_token']);
}
```

So if you send your form once and then reload page (without submitting form just url), `$form_token` variable is unknown because there is `$_SESSION['form_token']` is not empty and then in your form you have empty token.

If you had displaying errors turned on in PHP you would see in this case in PHP:

```
Undefined variable: form_token in
```